# Duplicate binding JSON result

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to bind JSON result to dynamically generated textboxes it is working fine on a single textbox but not working with dynamic generated textbox it is duplicating the same value on all textboxes, i'm sharing what i have done so far:

JQUERY:

```
function bindAutoComplete(classname) {
    $("." + classname).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                            }))
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        },
    });

}

function bindData() {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $('.inputs').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
        data: { 'term': amount },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.length > 0) {

                    $('.buyingprice').val(data[0].Price);
                }
                else {

                    $('.buyingprice').val('');
                }
            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            $('#error').html(jqXHR)
        }
    });
};

// fetch part number
$(document).ready(function () {
    bindAutoComplete('inputs');
    $('.inputs').keyup(bindData)
});

$("#AddMore").click(function () {

    $("#maintable").each(function () {

        var tds = '<tr>';

        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';

        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {

            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            //   bindData();
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
            $("#delete").fadeIn('200');
        }
        else {
            $(this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
            //    bindData();

        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
 <table id="maintable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Part No
            </th>
            <th>
                BP
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="inputs" type="text" name="abcd" id="PartNumber23" style="width:130px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="buyingprice text-box single-line" id="BuyingPrice" name="BuyingPrice" type="text" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output Image

[image: Result Image]

i'm getting result from autocomplete on all dynamic textboxes and binding the values to dynamic textboxes respectively but it is binding the same value on all dynamic textboxes. i have searched internet but couldn't found any solution. please guide me i'm stuck here from 2 days

Comment: As @Shaz suggested you can use POST cause the browser caches the get request for some time. If you need to use `GET` you can add a dynamic paramter like `'Admin/Ticket/GetPart?date' + (new Date())`. the browser will treate every request as a new request.

Comment: @Nilesh i have tried that method but still getting the same problem, i want to bind the values to dynamically generated textboxes, can i show u the image of the result?

Comment: you need to clear your browser cache first if you change the method type. Hit ctrl+f5 and use f12 network tarffic monitor tool to make sure you are sending the right request and getting the right data..

Comment: @Shaz i'm getting the right data and i have cleared the browser cache it is working all perfect on a simple textbox but when i add dynamic textbox only autocomplete is working on dynamic textbox but binding is not working on dynamic texbox.
i have updated the question and attached the image u can check, u can see the BP binds automatically on keyup event but it is not working on dynamic BP textbox

Comment: Where are you using binddata for dynamically created textboxes?

Comment: i can't see bindingdata either...are you running the script after the controls dynamically generated..???

Comment: @Shaz when i type in part no it send request to autocompelte method and get data in JSON and bind that data result into BP textbox it is working on a single textbox which is not dynamic but when i add dynamic textbox as u can see in the image only autocomplete is working but it is not binding the data to BP textbox. i'm calling bind data function on keyup event of all textboxes with ".input" class

Comment: @Nilesh when i type in part no it send request to autocompelte method and get data in JSON and bind that data result into BP textbox it is working on a single textbox which is not dynamic but when i add dynamic textbox as u can see in the image only autocomplete is working but it is not binding the data to BP textbox. i'm calling bind data function on keyup event of all textboxes with ".input" class

Comment: @Shaz and as u can see on "AddMore" click event i have comment the "bindData();" if i uncomment this line it will add the same BP value to dynamic textbox on click

Comment: Thats right, as @Stephen suggested the dynamically created textboxes are not bound to the binddata, for that you need to use the container which is a static element and holds those dynamically created textboxes, and then bind keyup event to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few potential problems. with you javascript. This

```
$('.inputs').keyup(bindData)
```

is binding the keyup only to elements with classname = "input" that existing when the DOM is created.  To ensure its bound to dynamically created elements, use

```
$("#maintable").on('keyup', '.inputs', function() {...
```

In `bindData(){..`, this line

```
var amount = $('.inputs').val();
```

gets the value of the **first** input with classname = "input" (not the one you may want).  This line

```
$('.buyingprice').val(data[0].Price);
```

sets the value of **all** inputs with classname = "buyingprice" to `data[0].Price`.

You need to use `$(this)` where you want to refer to the current element.

In `$("#AddMore").click(function () {...`

```
$("#maintable").each(function () {
```

seems pointless since you only appear to have one table with id = "maintable", and

```
bindAutoComplete('inputs');
```

is re-binding all inputs (including the ones you already bound).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer i have followed your instructions but now it is not binding anything to any textbox either dynamic or simple textbox

Comment: No your not. I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FuSwn/) to shown you how it works (and simplified some of your code - note the use of `clone()` to copy a row)

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is just copy and paste the row to the new row with the same values, i don't want same values i want every row result based on that row autocomplete result

Comment: You haven't posted your full html so I cant give you a full solution  There are 2 ways to solve this (1) create a 2nd tbody element (display:none) with one row containing with default (empty) inputs and clone that row or (2) amend the clones html to set the value attribute of all inputs to the default value

Comment: this is the complete HTML but there is a button at bottom with ID "AddMore", please help me i'm really stuck here from 2 days

Comment: Its not the complete html - your image shows 7 columns per row but the html has only 2!  I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FuSwn/1/) to add a new row using the first option above but I have no idea what you are wanting to do with the input names and id's (you can't duplicate the ID's).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55059/discussion-between-usama-sheikh-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using "GET" Type as GET method will cache the data in the browser. use "POST" if data is new on each request.

Don't forget to decorate your Controller method also with [HttpPost] as well.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                            }))
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: thanks for your code help but i'm still not binding the values to dynamically generated textboxes. can i show u the image here so that u will get more closer to problem?

Comment: i have attached the image to question